# WebShim canvas and IE8 document ready

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-8, webshim

I'm using webshim to get canvas working in IE8.

All of the drawing functionality is working mostly perfectly, but for some reason when I've used `$.webshims.polyfill('canvas');` my document ready handler doesn't fire.

I've tried using both jQuery's `$()` and the `$.webshims.ready('canvas', function() {` but neither appear to be working.

If I open the console and run `$.webshims.isReady('canvas')` by hand, it does return `false`. If I just use a `setTimeout` and then run my code everything draws correctly though, so it does seem that the canvas is loaded.

The code I'm using to load the canvas:

```
window.FlashCanvasOptions = { disableContextMenu: true };

$.webshims.setOptions( 'canvas', { type: 'excanvas' } );

$.webshims.polyfill('canvas');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you opened the console and looked wether there are any errors or logs? Are you using a real IE8 or IE10?

Comment: No errors in the logs at all - using real IE8.

Weird part is that I have a test case where `$()` is working and my main project works correctly if I just start drawing after an interval, although I obviously can't rely on a `setTimeout`.

As soon as I remove the `$.webshims.polyfill('canvas');` the `$()` works, so there's it's definitely something related to the polyfill.

Comment: This is weird. As a workaround you could use webshim.setOptions('waitReady', false);. To debug this thing, could you simply set two breakpoints in the excanvas file (use the one from the dev folder) at line 35 and 937. Hint: you can also use IE9 in IE8 mode for this.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: any news on this one???

Comment: I need to roll back to your version of excanvas to check - I needed the text methods, so I'd pulled the most recent one out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have changed to a different excanvas version. Simply take this version and copy the following code at the very end of the file:

```
(function(document){
webshims.addReady(function(context, elem){
    if(context == document){
        if(window.G_vmlCanvasManager && G_vmlCanvasManager.init_ ){
            G_vmlCanvasManager.init_(document);
        }
    }
    webshims.$('canvas', context).add(elem.filter('canvas')).each(function(){
        var hasContext = this.getContext;
        if(!hasContext && window.G_vmlCanvasManager){
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(this);
        }
    });
});
webshims.isReady('canvas', true);
})(document);
```

Comment: Were you using a modified version of the standard excanvas? That would make perfect sense - I'll let you know in ~12 hours.